# How to log 404 errors in Laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

Laravel doesn't log 404 errors by default. I want to change this behavior.

Most guides say to log it manually in the following block :

```
public function register(): void
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        // Handle 404 here
    });
}
```

but it seems like 404 exceptions don't even trigger this method for some reason.

Doing the following technically works but it's tedious to put everywhere I need it :

```
try {
     $model = User::findOrFail(99999);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
     Log::error($e);
     throw $e;
}
```

I'm using Laravel 10.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `stopIgnoring` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#ignoring-exceptions-by-type

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
 
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 */
public function register(): void
{
    $this->stopIgnoring(ModelNotFoundException::class);
 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why the first approach wasn't working as expected and better ways to handle 404 logging in Laravel 10.

Understanding the Issue

The reportable method within the App\Exceptions\Handler class is primarily designed to report exceptions for error tracking services, not specifically for logging every 404. This is why you weren't seeing the effect you expected.

Recommended Approaches

Here's how to effectively log 404 errors in Laravel 10:

1. Custom Exception Handler Middleware

Create a middleware (e.g., LogNotFoundRequests.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogNotFoundRequests
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($response->status() === 404) {
            Log::error('404 Not Found: ' . $request->path());
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in your app\Http\Kernel.php file. Add it to either your global middleware stack or a specific route group.

2. Event Listener

Create an event listener (e.g., LogNotFoundException.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class LogNotFoundException
{
    public function handle(NotFoundHttpException $event)
    {
        Log::error('404 Not Found: ' . $event->getRequest()->path());
    }
}
```

Register the listener in your App\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php file:

```
protected $listen = [
    // ... other events
    NotFoundHttpException::class => [
        LogNotFoundException::class,
    ],
];
```

Choosing a Method

Middleware: Good for simple, direct logging of the request path.
Event Listener: Offers more flexibility if you want more elaborate error handling, such as passing data to other systems or creating custom log messages.

Why Avoid try-catch Blocks

Manually adding try-catch blocks with ModelNotFoundException everywhere is less ideal because:

Repetition: It creates unnecessary code duplication.
Limited Control: It doesn't let you easily customize log messages or log levels.